# Add list formatted output as additional columns in table (powershell/powercli)

Tags: powershell, powercli

I'm using the following to collect some data that can be exported to a table format/CSV:

```
Get-VMHost  | Select Name,@{N="ESX Version";E={$_.version}},@{N="ESX Build";E={$_.build}}}}
```

I get the following as expected:

***Name ESX Version ESX Build

--------                                                                  -----------------                                                           -------------

host1                                       6.0.0                                                                           3029758

host2                                       6.0.0                                                                 3029758***

What I'd like to do is add code that creates a list of properties and convert/add them to additional columns in the same output.

When I add the following at the end of my code:

```
@{N="Installed Patches";E={($_ | Select-Object | Get-EsxCli).software.vib.list()}}
```

I get the last column:

Installed Patches

---

{VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.EsxCli.EsxC...

Seeing how I'd go about creating an additional column for each installed patch and associated field to get the output looking something like this:

***Name ESX Version ESX Build Patch ID Version Install Date AddField1  AddField2

--------                                                                  -----------------                                                           ------------- ------------- ----------- ----------------  --------------- ---------------

host1                                       6.0.0                                                                           3029758 PatchID PatchVersion PatchInstallDate AddField1_Data  AddField2_Data

host2                                       6.0.0                                                                 3029758 PatchID PatchVersion PatchInstallDate AddField1_Data  AddField2_Data***

I have a few different queries I'm also looking to add lists as columns to existing outputs so looking to adapt as needed.

Thanks

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: Working with version 3 Atm